# Create an office document, only after a click of a button with classic asp

Tags: html, asp-classic

I wanted to create a docx file of an HTML page with just a click.

This is how it goes, I have an HTML page with a "download" button at the bottom of the page. When I click the button, the page will be exported into docx file. How do I achieve this by using classic asp?

Here is what I did and the page is exported into ms word as soon as I run the coding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<%response.write("<h1><center>Welcome!</h1>")%>
<center><img src="http://www.themelab.com/wp-content/uploads/smiley.jpg" alt="Smiley" style="width:auto;height:auto;"></center>

<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<p>Click the button below to copy the page as word document.</p>

<button class="word-export"> Download </button> 
<%
    Response.Buffer = TRUE
    Response.ContentType = "application/msword"    
%>


</body>
</html>
```

I want it to be exported only after I click the button. or how do I run the code below after a click of the button?

```
<%
    Response.Buffer = TRUE
    Response.ContentType = "application/msword"    
%>
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a request to the page, for that you need a form and on submit of the form, get the output as ms word:

```
<%if Request("btn_download")<>"" Then 
'Only set the headers if this is request for download
    Response.Buffer = TRUE
    Response.ContentType = "application/msword"
    Response.AddHeader "content-disposition","attachment; filename=thefile.doc;"
end if
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<%response.write("<h1><center>Welcome!</h1>")%>
<center><img src="http://www.themelab.com/wp-content/uploads/smiley.jpg" alt="Smiley" style="width:auto;height:auto;"></center>

<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<%if Request("btn_download")="" Then 
'Show the download button only if the button has not been clicked.
%>
<p>Click the button below to copy the page as word document.</p>
<form>
<input type="submit" class="word-export" name="btn_download" value="Download">
</form>
<%End If%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May I know how can I open the page in *.docx instead of *.doc ? 

I tried "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" and "application/vnd.msword". Are these MIME affect the code in any ways?

Comment: Did  you try changing the filename to `thefile.docx`? My office installation is old and i cannot test it here right now.

Comment: Yes I did and turned out the file couldn't be opened with an error message "problem with its content".